# JBoss 7.1.1: add rt.jar of jre to classpath

Tags: jboss, runtime, classpath, jboss7.x

My goal is to deploy an ear file in JBoss 7.1.1. One of the classes in the ear file (which I cannot change) is using `sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil` class of JRE's **rt.jar**.

In my IDE (eclipse) resolves this class and it compiles normally. But when I try to deploy (the ear containing the class) on JBoss 7.1.1, it gives me `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/net/util/IPAddressUtil`. `JAVA_HOME` variable is set in my machine and I see that both JBoss and eclipse use the same JDK (1.6.X)

When I bundle the EAR with **rt.jar** in lib folder, the EAR deploys properly (which is a bad approach).

I have looked at [JBoss community](https://community.jboss.org/thread/175395) which says to configure as module for any third-party jars. However, the class I need is with in the **rt.jar**, I'm not in favor of adding it as module

Is there a way to configure JBoss 7.1.1 to manually look at `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/rt.jar` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason you don't see this class is because it's not part of the API. The solution is to fix your code to not use `sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil`. There is no guarantee that it won't be removed at some point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JBoss 7 use jboss-modules technology for modular class-loading, similar to OSGi. 
It will use rt.jar and a bunch of libraries in its own lib directory to start the application server itself.
But when it will load your web application, it will create a custom classloader which restricts what classes it will see, based on the module dependencies it declares.

To declare module dependencies, you need to include a  jboss-deployment-structure.xml in the META-INF directory of your EAR (or WEB-INF for a WAR). See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7. To declare a dependency on classes in the rt.jar, you need a <system> dependency:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <system export="true">
                <paths>
                    <path name="sun/net/util"/>
                </paths>
            </system>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

You could also try to extract the IPAddressUtil class and package it as a separate module.  You can get the sources from the openjdk, e.g. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/util/IPAddressUtil.java.html

Comment: Just bit of comment, Jboss7 is not OSGI based but it does support osgi, it is jboss-modules based.

Comment: it's better to change the pointer, than to change the bundles.

Answer (score 0):

[See wildfly developer guide#1.8. Accessing JDK classes](https://docs.wildfly.org/16/Developer_Guide.html)

Not all JDK classes are exposed to a deployment by default. If your deployment uses JDK classes that are not exposed you can get access to them using jboss-deployment-structure.xml with system dependencies:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <system export="true">
            <paths>
                <path name="sun/net"/>
            </paths>
        </system>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```